# Why do I got error while video capturing with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-18.04

The following code has now started to return an error to me:

```
cv2 import
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
capture.release()
```

return

```
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-qacpj5ci/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index
```

I have a video grabber connected and I had no problems with it earlier.

I don't see '/dev/video1' on my computer, but I see only '/dev/video0'.

From the information I found on the Internet, it seems to me that the most probable reason is that I did not close the capturing device.

I use ubuntu 18.04, python 3.6.9 and opencv-python===4.4.0.46.

I was running the code with jenkins as sudo (and sometimes the job was stopped manualy).

I tried to restart the computer and some other things I found on the Internet, but unfortunately nothing helped.

I'll add that at first I also couldn't run the webcam script in the computer (i.e. with parameter 0), but after some time I succeeded (in the meantime I was whisking some suspicious processes).

Comment: Did you try with cv2.VideoCapture(0)

Comment: When you unplugged camera, do you see any changing in /dev/video... ?

Comment: @LahiruJayasundara Yes, at first I couldn't run with a 0 argument, but now I'm recording from the camera.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk What do you mean by unplugged camera?